# Shopify Liquid: Paginating blog post based on tag

Tags: pagination, themes, shopify, liquid

I'm going to try my best to explain this, sorry if it seems confusing.

I have a customized theme. I'm trying to take articles from the blog and put them into 7 separate tagged pages. Essentially to create separate blog templates standard one blog template. The pages bring in a section that paginates by 6.

I'm able to bring the blog articles into the section and paginate, but I'm unable to filter out the unnecessary tags. When I use if/unless statements inside the pagination loop, it just didn't render the unnecessary ones but still paginated based on it, so I had 3 articles on the first page, 2 on the second, and so on. Which make sense why it would do that.

I've tried the 'where' filter on my assign tag and the paginate tag, didn't work. When I asked on the Shopify Slack someone mentioned using the Section Render API with the endpoint '/blogs/{blog_id}/tagged/{tag_id}' but the returns all of the HTML from that page and I don't know how I'd parse and paginate over that. The Section Render API documentation is wanting, to say the least. And my experience with APIs is limited

The closest I've come to answer an is this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60000460/12948634

The problem with the liquid solution is that I can apply a "view" to the tagged posts page but I still have to paginate over it. I still have to use the {% paginate blog.articles %} that apparently doesn't filter. Pagination isn't included in this theme and I'm not quite sure how to add that that to my 'blog-content.liquid' file without disturbing the main tagged page.

Any ideas? Code below:

```html
<div id="article-index-card-section" class="g-flex">
    {% assign blog = blogs.{blog_id} %}
    {% paginate blog.articles by 6 %}
        {% for article in blog.articles %}
            
                <div class="article-index-card g-vertical">
                    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
                        <img class="article-index-card-image" src="{{ article.image.src | img_url: 'master' }}">
                        <div class="article-index-card-text">
                            <h4>{{ article.title }}</h4>
                            <p class="t-body">{{ article.excerpt }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="article-index-card-btn btn">
                        <a href="{{ article.url }}">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
        {% endfor %}
        <div>
           {{ paginate | default_pagination: next: '>', previous: '<' }} 
        </div>
        
    {% endpaginate %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will probably go the JS route in this case.

Here is what will I probably do, I don't know if it will fit your needs.

#### Create a separate blog.ajax.liquid template

We will create a new blog template and we will keep only the HTML need for the page to make the request faster and strip unused HTML elements.

```
{% layout none %}

<div id="article-index-card-section" class="g-flex">
  {% paginate blog.articles by 6 %}
    {% for article in blog.articles %}
      <div class="article-index-card g-vertical">
          <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
              <img class="article-index-card-image" src="{{ article.image.src | img_url: 'master' }}">
              <div class="article-index-card-text">
                  <h4>{{ article.title }}</h4>
                  <p class="t-body">{{ article.excerpt }}</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="article-index-card-btn btn">
              <a href="{{ article.url }}">Learn More</a>
          </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div>
        {{ paginate | default_pagination: next: '>', previous: '<' }} 
    </div>
  {% endpaginate %}
</div>
```

That's why we add the line `{% layout none %}` at the top to remove all of the HTML output from the default layout and only output the HTML on the template we create.

#### Make fetch request to that new template

We make a fetch request to the blog but we must specify that it must used the newly created template and not the default one.

```
fetch('/blogs/{blog_handle}/tagged/{tag}?view=ajax').then(res => res.text()).then(res => {
  document.querySelector('.blog-holder').innerHTML = res;
})
```

For that we add the `?view=ajax` to the end of the request, where the `ajax` part is the name of the template we created after `blog.ajax.liquid`.

This request needs to be done for each separate blog, so if you have 10 blogs you will do this request 10 times for each one.

#### Pagination request

The pagination request will be similar to the request of the blog but you will need to add the `page=2` argument to the request where the `2` is the page number.

So something like so:

```
fetch('/blogs/{blog_id}/tagged/{tag_id}?view=ajax&page=2').then(res => res.text()).then(res => {
  document.querySelector('.blog-template').innerHTML = res;
})
```

#### Blog main page

I will probably create a static section, where you will be able to select which blog goes on this page.

```
{%- for block in section.blocks -%}
    {%- assign _block = block.settings -%}
    {%- assign block_blog = _block.blog -%}
  <div class="blog-template" data-handle="{{block_blog}}">
    
  </div><!-- /.blog-template -->  
{%- endfor -%}

<script>
  document.querySelectorAll('.blog-template').forEach(item => {
    const handle = item.getAttribute('data-handle');
    // make fetch request and the logic for your tags
  })
</script>

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Blogs",
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "blog",
      "name": "Blog",
      "settings": [
        {
          "type": "blog",
          "id": "blog",
          "label": "Choose a blog"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

This will be my personal choice of direction I go, I don't know if it will fit your needs.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much for the reply, I was hoping this would get your attention. I've got it working except for the paginated pages. It paginates currently, but I'm not clear on where that code needs to go to get it to work properly on pages after the first page.

Comment: @Jason for the pagination you need to target the pagination links generated from `{{ paginate | default_pagination: next: '>', previous: '<' }}` and make ajax request to their `href` (not 100% sure if the view argument is there, but if it's not you must add it). I assume that you use different pagination for each blog and not a global one that controls all of the blogs at the same time.